# Finding the point through which the tangent passes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

> A hyperbola passes through the point $P=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$  and has foci $(\pm 2,0)$. Show that the tangent at $P$ passes through the point $(2\sqrt{2},3\sqrt{3})$.

**Attempt:**

So the equation of hyperbola is

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

We have been given $ae=2$ and a point on hyperbola.

So it gives us two equations:

$$a^2+b^2=4\tag{1}$$

$$2b^2-3a^2=(ab)^2\tag{2}$$

Substituting $b^2=4-a^2$ and solving with $(2)$, I get the equation $a^4-9a^2+8=0$. This gives me the value of $a$ to be $\{1,-1,2\sqrt{2},-2\sqrt{2}\}$. None of this satisfies the condition of hyperbola... What did I do wrong?

Comment: The RHS of (2) should be $a^2b^2$ but that looks like a typo. The rest seems correct to me. We can throw away negative values for a (and b), since only the squares appear in the equation of the hyperbola. The $a = 2\sqrt{2}$ solution leads to $b^2 = -4$, so it can be thrown away as well, leaving you with $a=1$. Not sure why you think you did something wrong.

Comment: From the foci and point $P$ on the hyperbola, the equation is $x^2-y^2/3=1$. Now the tangent at $P=(x(P),y(P))=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is $x x(P)-y y(P)/3=1$ or $x\sqrt{2}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}=1$, which the point $(2\sqrt{2},3\sqrt{3})$ satisfies.

Comment: But the focii isn't on x axis for a=1...... Shouldn't it be wrong

Comment: a>b in my opinion

Comment: The focii position does not depend on the the fact that $a<b$ or vice versa.

Comment: Okay. I messed this here. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a property of hyperbolas that leads to a simple way of solving this problem instead of trying to find an equation of the hyperbola: the tangent to a hyperbola bisects the angle formed by the lines to its foci.

The lines through $\left(\sqrt2,\sqrt3\right)$ and the two foci have direction vectors $\mathbf v=\left(\sqrt2-2,\sqrt3\right)$ and $\mathbf w=\left(\sqrt2+2,\sqrt3\right)$. The relevant angle bisector has direction vector $\|\mathbf w\|\mathbf v+\|\mathbf v\|\mathbf w = \left(4,4\sqrt6\right)$, i.e., the slope of the tangent at $P$ is $\sqrt6$. With this slope in hand, verifying that $\left(2\sqrt2,3\sqrt3\right)$ lies on this line should be a simple matter.

I’m not sure why you think that you’ve done anything wrong in your attempt at a solution, though. You just haven’t carried it all the way through. You can discard negative values of $a$ right off the bat. If you substitute $a=2\sqrt2$ into the first equation, you get $8+b^2=4$, which has no real solutions, so that value can also be discarded. For $a=1$, $b=\pm\sqrt3$, and of course we discard the negative solution again.

Comment: I thought since focii was given to be on x axis then a>b

Comment: $$\|\mathbf w\|\mathbf v+\|\mathbf v\|\mathbf w = \left(4,4\sqrt6\right)$$.. Is this a standard form of angle bisector in vector form

Comment: @Zerix Yes. If you have same-length vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$, their angle bisectors are $\mathbf v\pm\mathbf w$. Equivalently, you could make each one a unit vector by dividing by its norm.